# Autogenerate values in text box

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I have a text box named as number and I want the values to be autogenerated.

```
<label>Number</</label>
<input id="numb" name="number" type="text"/>
```

Here in the text box field value has to be automatically generate. Like 1, 2 and so on.

I have a text box where the values have to be auto filled starting from 1 and on click of save button the new value should be filled in the text box and so on.

How do I fill those values?

Can someone tell me how do I do that?

Comment: Might be quite tricky to give you an idea of where to go - how exactly would you decide what number would go into the box? Are there multiple text boxes for multiple numbers?

Comment: Post an output example please.

Comment: How does the input fields are created?

Comment: What do you mean by auto generated? do you want a random number each time you load the page??? What value do you need?

Comment: something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/6ZWNZ/

Comment: @ all
Thanks a lot for ur reply.

I have a text box where the values have to be auto generated starting from 1 and on click of save button the new value should be filled in the text box and so on.

Comment: should the number keep on changing or a random number per page load?

Comment: Hi, initially the text box value should be 1. Only after the save button is clicked The new value in the text box will be 2. So each time after you click on save button ,new value should be generated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var t, max, i;
function Increase(amount) {
max = amount;
i = parseInt(document.getElementById("count").value);
t = setInterval("SetIncrease()", 1000);
}
function SetIncrease() {
document.getElementById("count").value = ++i;
if(i == max) {
clearTimeout(t);
}
}
</script>
<body onLoad="Increase(36);">
<input id="count" type="text" value="1"  >
</body>
</html>
```

**If dont need max limit you can remove that condition**

Comment: Hello evryone! 

Thanks a lot for your reply.

But my question is Only on click on save button, new value should be generated in the text box.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jQuery text function](http://api.jquery.com/text/)! to fill the text box at given times that you can define with **setInterval**.

Comment: this is not a "text box" but an input which used [val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/) to modify its value.